# How to access to container search Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox

How can I access the container that appears when I write a url in the address bar? I have a search engine, I just need to show an icon plus a url in the panel[image]

researching I could only get a basic javascript

```
function createMenuItem(engines) {
  for (let engine of engines) {
    browser.menus.create({
     id: engine.name,
     title: engine.name,
     contexts: ["selection"]
   });
 }
}
browser.search.get().then(createMenuItem);
browser.menus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  browser.search.search({
    query: info.selectionText,
    engine: info.menuItemId
  });
});


//php get variable code
if(isset($_GET["term"])) {
        $term = $_GET["term"]; 
    } else {
        header('location: '.$url.'');
    }
//json
"search_url": "https://127.0.0.1/search/search?term={term}"
```

result

[image]

I tried it with

```
${term}
$term
{term}
term
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that the `browser.search` namespace only has two functions: [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/search/get) and [`search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/search/search) but nothing to add or modify search engines.

Instead, you declare the search engine as a [`search_provider`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_settings_overrides) in your extension's `manifest.json` file.

Mozilla provides an example for how to add a search engine [here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/discogs-search). The manifest.json included in the example speaks for itself.

---

### manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Discogs search engine",
  "description": "Adds a search engine that searches discogs.com",
  "version": "1.0",
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "55"
    }
  },
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "name": "Discogs",
      "search_url": "https://www.discogs.com/search/?q={searchTerms}",
      "keyword": "disc",
      "favicon_url": "https://www.discogs.com/favicon.ico",
      "is_default": false,
      "encoding": "UTF-8"
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you, I need to wait 22 hours to grant the reward

Comment: me again, I have a problem with getting the text that is written inside the address bar, try {term} ${term} $term, I just added the php code

Comment: @qwerty Your url needs to be `https://127.0.0.1/search/search?term={searchTerms}`
Firefox is looking for the string `{searchTerms}` and, if found, replaces it with the string the user enters.